# Control CLI of external program using Matlab

Tags: matlab, automation, external

I want to open an external program and than excecute some commands with the program's own CLI (command line interface) using matlab.
I'm able to open the program with

```
!myProgram.exe &
```

Is there any possibility to access the program CLI after opening the program? Thank You!

Comment: When you do `!` you are running commands in the OS command line. So this is not a MATLAB problem as I see. If you can do it in your OS CLI, you can do it in MATLAB, a priori

Comment: It would probably help to specify what operating system you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`system`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command.

> **system**
>
> Execute operating system command and return output